# Write a specifc key to parse object with Twig

Tags: php, object, twig

I can't find the way to parse an array with a generate key with **Twig** :

My object post :

```
[blocks_content_0_title] => Title0
[blocks_content_1_title] => Title1
[blocks_content_2_title] => Title3
```

With Twig I can get value normally : **post.blocks_content_0_title** and it display **Title0**

But in my code I need to push specific key with variable for display value. And I can't parse with a classical twig **for** my object

> My question is, how to insert a variable in key ?

Examples (and it doesn't work) :

```
{{ post.blocks_content_~myNumber~_title }}
{{ post['blocks_content_'~myNumber~'_title'] }}
```

Sorry for this horrible english ;)
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `attribute()`:

```
{{ attribute(post, 'blocks_content_' ~ myNumber ~ '_title') }}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html

Personally, I'd consider refactoring so I don't have to do this in a template.

Comment: Thx a lot it's working, and you right to refactoring. I'll try to do it in controller.